# node.js mkdirp privilege issue

Tags: node.js

i am trying to run node.js from an account called "foo" and wish to create a directory in the "bar" area:

/home/bar/public_html/openDirectory/

i am trying to use mkdirp and am getting the following error:

```
 process.setuid(555) ;  //  555 is foo's UID
 mkdirp( '/home/bar/public_html/openDirectory' , function(err)  {
```

> { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/bar/public_html/openDirectory']
>    errno: 3,
>    code: 'EACCES',
>     path: '/home/bar/public_html/openDirectory' }

mkdirp works fine for me when i run as root or when i write into foo's area, but when i try to mkdirp in another users area, i get the EACCESS error.

the   /home/bar/public_html/openDirectory   area is temporarily set with 777 protection just to see if i could get past this problem which did not work:

> drwxrwxrwx 1 bar bar 4096 Nov 18 12:34 openDirectory

i was tempted to look into seeing if i could temporarily grant the node process root privilege, but wanted to run the issue by some others first.

any suggestions?

Comment: did you make sure with a process.getuid that the uid is really set?
also does foo really have permission to make a dir in bar's home?

Comment: hi cdanea - excellent question.  i just **su**'ed to foo and was not able to even cd into the bar directory in spite of the 777 protection much less create a new directory.  makes me wonder about  **chattr** or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be sudo user if you want to create directory in other user's home directory. You must use `sudo` to do this kind of job.